# Are the binomial coefficients unique?

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $a,x,b,y$ be integers. 
Can we find rationals $u,v,w,t$ such that $$(ax+by)^3=ux^3+vx^2y+wxy^2+ty^3\neq 0$$
where $$(u,v,w,t)\neq ( 1, 3a^2b, 3ab^2, 1)$$
The answer looks trivial but can one prove it?

Comment: Is that equation supposed to be true for all $a,b,x,y$?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: then obviously the answer is yes. Choose $a=b=x=y=0$ and any $u,v,w,t$ works.

Comment: I did mention that $$ax+by\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ux^3+vx^2y+wxy^2+ty^3=a^3x^3+3a^2byx^2+3ab^2y^2x+b^3y^3$$ is an equaliy involving two polynomials respect to x. since $ ( x^3, x^2, x, 1)$
 is a basis then, $$(u,v,w,t)= ( a^3, 3a^2b, 3ab^2, b^3)$$